# Overriding aspnetcore appsettings.json key value on application startup for integration tests

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetcore-environment

I am in the process of writing some aspnetcore integration tests that run against an instance of SQL Server running on docker. I plan to use xUnit collections and start a separate instance of SQL Server container on a different port for a specific collection of tests. So multiple SQL Server instances running on different ports.
I have created a separate `appsettings.testing.json` file that will be loaded when the test `host` is started. This settings json file has the connection string which the test `host` will use to connect when its started for testing.

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "TestDb": "Server=.;Database=MyDb;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;user id=sa;password=Password01!;TrustServerCertificate=True"
  }
}
```

Is there a way for me to override the value for key `TestDb` when I am starting the test `host`? As before starting the host I start the SQL container on a specific port and want the `host` to use a amended connection string that would have the `port` mentioned and connect to it.

I have been checking the documentation but unable to understand if there is a way to do this at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override settings when configuring the test web host:

```cs
builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(configBuilder =>
{
    configBuilder.AddInMemoryCollection(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["ConnectionStrings:TestDb"] = "connection string here"
    });
});
```

In your case the in-memory configuration would work best.
You can also add user secrets etc. here.

Comment: thanks @juunas that worked.